# how to use mysqli_fetch_array in wordpress $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

can someone help me convert this to wordpress friendly code.

basically, im creating a custom page where i want to dispaly `json_encode` arrays. based on the member ID input.

so if i append `id=3` on my custom wordpress page. i want to display the associated name for that id.

when i run below code and type this on my browser `http://localhost/site/?page_id=43&id=3`
i only get this on my page `{"result":[]}`

this is my code. i just need to know how to make `mysqli_fetch_array` work in wordpress.

```
/*
Template Name: getID
*/

global $wpdb;
if (isset($_GET['id']) === true && empty($_GET['id']) === false) {      
    $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `memberid` WHERE `memberid` = `$_GET['id']`");

   $array = array();

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($array, array('name' => $row [2]);
   }

   echo json_encode(array("result" => $array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i managed to figure this out. since i wanted to retrieve the numerical Array.

i need to add `ARRAY_N` on my query

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `table`, ARRAY_N );
```

and just found out, that `while` loop won't work. so i used `foreach`

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
        array_push($array, array('name' => $row[2]);
    }
echo json_encode(array("result" => $array));
```